# Subscribing to a service from component in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have a service that needs to return the date every second:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ClockService {

    mydate: Date;

  constructor() {
  }

  getClock(): Observable<any> {
      setInterval(()=>{
          this.mydate = new Date();
          return this.mydate;
      }, 1000);
  }

}
```

I'm trying to subscribe to the `getClock()` function to update `mydate` in my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ClockService} from './clock.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {



  constructor(private clockService: ClockService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.clockService.getClock().subscribe(res => this.mydate = res));
  }

}
```

I'm getting an error of, `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

I'm new to Angular 2 and the docs aren't helping.

Comment: have you registered that service as a provider in `app.module`?

Comment: you should `return` the `setInterval`

Answer (score 2):

You should return an `Observable` at your service function first.

```
getClock(): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.mydate = new Date();
      observer.next(this.mydate);
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to implement `setInterval` with Rx.

Here's another option with [`Observable.interval`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) which creates an Observable that emits a new value at the specified interval, which is exactly what you want to do:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ClockService {    
  getClock(): Observable<Date> {
      return Observable.interval(1000).map(() => new Date());
  }
}
```

[See it in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tzyzfr)

`Observable.interval()` will emit a series of integers `1, 2, 3, ...`, whose value you simply discard (`() =>`) and replace with a `Date`, using `.map()`.

You can keep your `HeaderComponent` unchanged.

Note: I've removed the assignment to `this.mydate` because it doesn't *seem* to be needed. I've noticed that many people moving to angular create unnecessary intermediary member variables out of reflex, when a purely functional solution suffices. If I've been overly presumptuous and you need it, you can always put it back.

You also don't need an empty `constructor` in Angular, so I removed that too.

You *do* need the two additional `import`s, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually returning an observable but instead `void` in `getClock()`.

See https://angular.io/guide/observables

Instead do something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ClockService {

  private $timer = new Observable(obs => {
      setInterval(() => {
          obs.next(new Date());
      }, 1000);
  });

  constructor() {
  }

  getClock(): Observable<Date> {
      return this.$timer;
  }

}
```